# Moving a file from within the Solution

Tags: c#

I don't know if it's possible, but i wanted to ask and get some help.

So i have an .txt file inside my solution, and i was wondering if it would be possible to move it to desktop by a button in my C# Program. Picture to [Solution Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoFKQ.png)

So let's say i compiled my C# Project, i would want it to by a button press to move that .txt file to desktop that is inside my Program.

Like a VirtualBox that enigma has.

What i have tried is, but whenever i run program it just tries to find the .txt file externally, and not the one inside the program.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sourcePath = Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.FullName;
        string destinationPath = @"C:\";
        string sourceFileName = "TextFile1.txt";
        string destinationFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".xml"; // Don't mind this. I did this because I needed to name the copied files with respect to time.
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, sourceFileName);
        string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationFileName);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
        }
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
    }
```

Returns
[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzaWn.png)

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what i tried what just FileStream fs = File.Create(path))

Comment: But that it cant find the path within the program, it just tries to find the .txt file externally outside the program

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the concept of an *embedded resource*.

Comment: Updated the code, no idea why it cant find the file inside the solution.

Comment: it just cant find the file in the solution directory